# Upgrade to 5.70 caused issues; incomplete or flawed version or?

Tags: upgrade

I upgraded to the latest release last night and the upgrade appeared to have succeeded, but there were issues as I did it—out of memory issues on the sever (which I think I resolved now by editing the correct php.ini file), so may not have completed all tasks.

Symptoms:

1. Status page does not show anything at all
2. Going to the CiviCRM menu initially results in an error, but refreshing browser immediately resolves it.
3. Log shows
   Error: Undefined class constant 'MAJOR_VERSION' in GuzzleHttp\Utils::defaultUserAgent() (line 116 of ... /sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php).

CiviCRM Cron results in
function should not be reachable Caller: CRM_Contact_BAO_Query::whereClauseSingle Array ( [civi.tag] => deprecated )

User deprecated function: function should not be reachable Caller: CRM_Contact_BAO_Query::whereClauseSingle in CRM_Core_Error::deprecatedWarning() (line 1129 of .../public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php).

Warning: file_get_contents(https://latest.civicrm.org/stable.php?format=summary): Failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in CRM_Utils_VersionCheck->pingBack() (line 297 of .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/VersionCheck.php).

Ideas and solutions?

"CIVI_VERSION": "5.70.0",
"CMS_VERSION": "7.98", (Drupal)
domain is using php 7.4 (higher versions are right now resulting in website errors.) shell for upgrade was using php 8.1

Answer (score 2):

Check your extensions - you may have one using an older version of Guzzle. See if there is a newer version of the extension and upgrade it.  Alternatively, disable it to get things running again.

You may have more issues if there were memory problems causing steps of the upgrade to fail.  You might be better to restore the backup you did just before upgrading and rerun the upgrade with your modified php.ini